# ASP .NET 4 project working with MVC 4 project single login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have an ASP .NET 4 project which I've attached a MVC project to. I have referrenced them correctly and I can get from the ASP .NET4 project to the MVC via href="MVC/Home".

My issue is that the ASP .NET4 project controls the login. This means when I log in on through the ASP project and navigate to the MVC project, it constantly tries to redirect me to the ASP login page but with the Virtural Directory extension (eg. Localhost:8080/MVC). This cause a 404 error which is understandable as MVC/login.aspx doesn't exist.

How do I check in the MVC project if the user has already logged in through the ASP project? Which is the only and will only be method of logging in.

The ASP projects web config referrences:

```
authentication mode="Forms">
      forms name="" path="~/" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" /
    /authentication>
```

The MVC project doesn't have anything to do with authentation and literally only has a one controller (HomeController) and view (index) which has some plain text on.

Any help would be really great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the web.config files of both projects make sure that they both use the same keys and the same httpRuntime:

```
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="X" decryptionKey="X" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
```

You can use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/ to generade valid keys.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue was that the <htttpRuntime> was different in both project but also the .NET versions were different which wasn't something I noticed but it is all working now. Thanks